# Google Map API can't work in Android Device which don't have google framework service,what should I do?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I developed an application using google map android API via google play services,If the android device has google framework, it could be run nice, else it couldn't run well.

But android devices in China don't have google framework because of the policy.We tried to use openstreet api,but it is too slow in our country.

Thanks.

Comment: So what is the question?